# Auralise Audacity annotations / Generate audio click track from list of click times

Tags: linux, audio, audacity

I'm trying to annotate musical audio file in Audacity and then "listen" to annotations along with the file to check they are placed right. I haven't found an Audacity plugin that does it, but when I export Audacity labels I get a file like:

```
3.558390    
4.248639    
4.910771    
5.632766    
6.349320    
...
```

This time of file (in seconds) where point labels were placed. Maybe there's a tool (or maybe you can do it programmatically (in C++ on Linux preferably)) to easily generate such a click track? I would be then able to mix it with original file and listen to inspect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found two ways to solve this issue:

Write your own plugin in Nyquist (what I'm trying to do), I received great help on the Audacity forum:
http://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=68752

Use Sonic Visualiser:
http://www.sonicvisualiser.org/

This program combines two important features: insertion of annotations when audio is played and auralisation (different sounds available).